# How to disable past time time when the current date is today, enable all time if date is not today?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap-datetimepicker by eonasdan.
I have two datetimepicker in my page. One is for date of arrival and the other one is for time of arrival.

```
$('#dateOfArrival').datetimepicker({
    format : 'L',
    minDate : new Date(),
    keepInvalid : true
});

$('#timeOfArrival').datetimepicker({
    format : 'LT',
    minDate : moment()
});
```

I use two datetimepicker because that is the requirement.

I tried to call this function onchange of dateOfArrival but nothing is changed.

```
function setDateOfArrivalTime() {
    $("#timeOfArrival").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", new Date($("#dateField").val());
}
```

Here is the html code

```
<div class='input-group date' id='dateOfArrival'>
<input type="text" class="form-control requiredField" id="dateField" onchange="setDateOfArrivalTime();" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
<span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
```

```
<div class='input-group date' id='timeOfArrival' style="">
<input type='text' class="form-control requiredField" id="timeField"/>
<span class="input-group-addon">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" placeholder="hh:mm"></span>
</span>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: params od date time picker is object you can use {defaultDate: "02/08/2017"}

Comment: It didn't answer the question sir @VinodLouis

Comment: see this link for disabling dates pass a relevant timestamp http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates

Answer (score 0):

Eonasdan datetime picker has no `change` event, use [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) instead. Moreover function like [`minDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate) should be accessed using `.data("DateTimePicker")`, as the docs says:

> **Note** All functions are accessed via the `data` attribute e.g. `$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()`

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#dateOfArrival').datetimepicker({
  format : 'L',
  minDate : new Date(),
  keepInvalid : true
}).on('dp.change', function(e){
  // Set timepicker value to let the timepicker work
  $("#timeOfArrival").data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date);
  $("#timeOfArrival").data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});

$('#timeOfArrival').datetimepicker({
  format : 'LT',
  minDate : moment(),
  useCurrent: false
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='dateOfArrival'>
  <input type="text" class="form-control requiredField" id="dateField" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<div class='input-group date' id='timeOfArrival' style="">
  <input type='text' class="form-control requiredField" id="timeField" placeholder="hh:mm"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

PS. I do not understand why you are setting `minDate` to a time picker depending on the value of the datepicker.

Comment: I can't edit the time picker no matter what date I select. It is stuck in 12:00..

Comment: @Ishkar I've updated my answer fixing the snippet, however setting `minDate` depending on the other picker value does not makes sense to me.

Comment: it's working now! And that's a pretty close answer the only problem remaining is I can't select the date now. I can only select the date tommororw, but thanks man! It works! :)

Comment: BTW to answer your question about why I set the min date in time picker it is because I want to disable the past time depends on the current date. But now I realized, after reading your answer that I dont have to do it. Thanks man.

Comment: You can date from tomorrow because of `minDate : new Date()` in the `#dateOfArrival`. If the answer solved your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted.